# Lots of images in each ID

Tags: sql, database

I have a SQL database and I have lots of URL links for images for each id. I have created many columns for each link which I think it is not useful, the problem is I have rows with up to 20 columns and some rows without any data in those columns. So please is there different way to insert lots of link to an id without opening many columns?

Comment: For a sequence of homogenous items (i.e. a User can have 0..M Pictures), use "many rows". This is called "database normalization". Now, if each *fixed set of images* image serves a different role, *parts* can be turned into [heterogenous] tuples. I.e., imagine there are *only* 3 types of images: `(thumbnailImg, signatureImg, fullsizeImg)`. When and where to change which dimension is used varies - but it is usually quite obvious based on answering "how many?" and "how do the roles differ?"

Comment: @user2246674 the elements are fixed.

Comment: Can each be given a *distinct role* or are they Picture1, Picture2, .. PictureN? Is each column *required*? Is there additional shared fields such as Description? How will these columns be queried/used?

Comment: Each columns are like Picture1, Picture2, .. PictureN.

Comment: Then *use multiple rows* - even if there is a small maximum value for N, it represents a *homogenous sequence*. Databases are *designed* to work with many, many, many rows - JOINs and Relational Algebra can only change the set size along rows. For instance, to select all images for a particular user, all I would need to do is `SELECT description, url FROM image WHERE user = {userId}`. Easy - no need to handle if an [image] column is null, because a row is created only where there *is* a value.

Comment: I have edited my question to be more clear I hope this remove HOLD option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you actually have the correct idea. You *want* to have a row for each image rather than multiple columns. From what you described, your structure could look like:

```
url
-----------
urlId
urlAddress

image
-----------
imageId
filename

imageUrl
-----------
imageId
urlId
```

This structure allows there to be many `urlId`s for each `imageId`.

If you're asking for an efficient way to actually load the data, there are various methods depending on which DBMS you're using.

Comment: I am asking for more an efficient way because some id has 10 images link and some other 2 while I have 10 columns which I always have empty columns.

Comment: I am using the database from go daddy.

Comment: I would not have separate relations for URL/Image; but would rather simply have an Images relation with filename/url/description/we. Not all [potential] redundancy is useful or desirable to eliminate. In any case, *Use the rows, Luki*. :D

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi It seems like you're describing a non-normalized structure where you have some rows with up to 10 columns and some rows without any data in those columns. I would recommend that you spend some time reading about normalization. The solution I proposed wold resolve the issue you're describing.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Ok I will search about the normalization and I hope it works.